# selecting multiple labels on a windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

suppose I have drawn 1000 labels on a windows form in like a grid formation and each label is uniquely identified (eg: S001, S002,...S999) in a 10 by grid formation.  Would it be possible to draw a rectangle around some of the labels and thus selecting only those labels in the rectangle. Then i could change the for example the colour of those labels.

you may ask what I'm trying to acheive; I want to draw rectangles so they represent car bays in like a parking lot, by selecting some bays and changing colour then i can say they reserved and so forth also i can store the labels names in a database and change colour of the 'bays' if the bay is occupied or not and if it is occupied then use a mousehover event to bring up the vehicle info via a pop up or tooltiptext.

Can this be done?

Comment: do you want to draw a rectangle at runtime, on the form, and detect all labels falling inside such rectangle?

Comment: yes Davide, the user then can choose a certain block of bays(labels) to reserve so he can do some planning for future

Comment: This may not the answer that you are looking for but I would suggest not using so many windows controls. Remember every one of those label (or any Windows control for that matter) will have it's own processing to do which may be irrelevant for what you are doing. They will steal a bit of CPU every time they want to process their messages. Of course using controls is the easy way but not the best and efficient. Google for GDI related solutions from Bob Powell and you will learn a lot from his answers. Again - as I said - this may not be your answers but may improve your application overall.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. In WPF you could have achieved this much easier though. Just store a collection of your "lot" instances view models, and color each one appropriately through `Color={Binding LotColor}`

As for Windows Forms, one way is to iterate through all of the label control, and those, who's names are of a taken parking lot, will get their border (to draw a rectangle) and the Font Color properties adjusted respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own class for managing all your Label objects. It can have a method such as `public List<Label> GetLabelsInRectangle(Rectangle rectangle)` to provide a list of all the objects you want to recolor. I suppose internally it could use a two-dimensional array of Label objects.

Comment: so it can be done, sigh. wish i was good in C#, but i guess 1 step at a time